# Locate link in string and change to HTML link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm aware there are other answers to similar questions, however I have tried code examples I previously found and cannot get any of them to work.

I want to locate whether a string contains a url (starting with `http` or `https`) and then convert that link into an actual HTML link by adding `<a>` tags around it.

This is the code I have:

```
$text = 'Yummy brunch http://t.co/5AlmSPZeRd';

    if ((strpos($text,'http') !== false)) {
        echo "yep!";
        preg_replace('!(http|https)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?%=&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $text);
    }
```

While my "yep!" message does show (proving that the `if` statement is correct), the `preg_replace` doesn't occur. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. In other news I had no idea "!" could be used as a delimiter.

Comment: did you `echo` the `preg_replace`?

Comment: Andrei P.: http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters - you really have a wide range of characters you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$text = 'Yummy brunch http://t.co/5AlmSPZeRd';

if ((strpos($text,'http') !== false)) {
    echo "yep!";
    $text = preg_replace('!https?://\S+!', "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>", $text);
}
```

Comment: Yep, just realised this. I'm an idiot. Forgot to assign the `preg_replace` to the var.

Comment: Don't worry, everybody have done this at least once.

Comment: @Francesca: note that unless you absolutely want to print `yep!`, the test with `strpos` before a `preg_replace` is totally useless. If you want to know if at least a replacement was made, you can use the "count" parameter of `preg_replace`